# Python Bokeh Tabs layout tabs_location update

Tags: python-3.x, tabs, bokeh

I am creating a bokeh dashboard, attempting to incorporate Tabs in the layout. I need to move the tab location to the right (preferably bottom-right) of the Panel but am hitting this error:

> AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'tabs_location' to Tabs

The Tabs class does have this attribute according to the source code:

```
    tabs_location = Enum(Location, default="above", help="""
The location of the buttons that activate tabs.
""")
```

The error comes from the Tabs() call in the below MWE. If this is left out the code works but figure and widget positioning is disturbed from single figure placement.

The basic layout I am looking for can be seen by replacing:

```
row3a = row(tabs,wb1)
```

with:

```
row3a = row(t1,wb1)
```

MWE:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Select, TextInput, Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.models.widgets import Paragraph

t1 = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=420, title=None)
t1.toolbar_location='right'
t1.toolbar.logo=None
tab1 = Panel(child=t1,title="TPF")

t2 = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=420, title=None)
t2.toolbar_location='right'
t2.toolbar.logo=None
tab2 = Panel(child=t2,title="Prob")

tabs = Tabs(tabs=[ tab1, tab2 ],tabs_location='right')

select3a1 = Select(title="Var:", value="No", options=["No","Yes"])

category_options = {'No':[""],'Yes':["V1","V2"]}
select3a2 = Select(title="Category:", value="", options=category_options[select3a1.value])

tar_info = Paragraph(text = f'Tar: ')
mem_info = Paragraph(text = f'gm: ')

wb1 = widgetbox(tar_info,mem_info,select3a1,select3a2)

row3a = row(tabs,wb1)

menu_db_id = [("db1", "id1"), ("db2", "id2")]

drop_db_id = Select(title="Database",options=["db2","db1"],width=100)
id_inp = TextInput(title="ID",width=200)
s_butt = Button(label = 'Search',width=50,height=50)

s_sel = Paragraph(text=f'Selected: ',width=100)

row3b = row(widgetbox(drop_db_id,width=120),widgetbox(id_inp,width=250),widgetbox(s_butt,width=100),widgetbox(s_sel))

f3 = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=200, title=None)
f3.toolbar.logo=None

col_targ = column(row3b,row3a,f3)

f4 = figure(plot_width=700, plot_height=700, title=None)
f4.toolbar_location='left'
f4.toolbar.logo=None

row3 = row(f4,col_targ)

show(row3)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Bokeh v1.1.0 this code will work:

```
from bokeh.plotting import save, figure
from bokeh.models import Paragraph, Panel, Tabs, Column
from bokeh.util.browser import view

template = """
{% block postamble %}
<style>
.bk-root .bk-tabs-header .bk-tab {
    background-color: cyan;
    width: 100px;
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;

    position: relative;
    left: 400px; 
}

.bk-root .bk-tabs-header .bk-tab.bk-active{
    background-color: yellow;
    color: blue;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;

    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
}

.bk-root .bk-tabs-header .bk-tab:hover{
    background-color: yellow

    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
}

</style>
{% endblock %}
"""

p = Paragraph(text = "Another tab", width = 600)

plot = figure()
plot.line(x = [1, 2], y = [3, 4])
tabs = [Panel(title = 'Tab1', child = plot)]
tabs.append(Panel(title = 'Tab2', child = p))

save(Column(Tabs(tabs = tabs, width = 600, tabs_location = 'below')), template = template)
view("tabs_styles_demo.html")
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Bokeh Tabs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.panels.html) don't support location. You can see that on the [documentation page](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.panels.html) by expanding the JSON Prototype. However, you can position your Tabs where ever you like on the screen by overwriting the default Bokeh "tabs css classes" or by adding `css_classes` attribute to your components like in this example:

> Important: works for Bokeh v1.0.4 but doesn't work anymore for v1.1.0

css_classes_demo.py

```
from bokeh.plotting import save, show, figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Div, Paragraph, Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.util.browser import view

template = """
{% block postamble %}
<style>
.custom {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em; }
.custom-1 {
    border: 3px solid #2397D8; }
.custom-2 {
    border: 3px solid #14999A;
    background-color: whitesmoke;}
.bk-root .bk-bs-nav-tabs {
    background-color: cyan;
    width: -webkit-calc(100%);
    width:    -moz-calc(100%);
    width:         calc(100%);
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 460px;
    top: 640px;
    width: 126px; }
</style>
{% endblock %} """

p = Paragraph(text = "The tabs below were configured with additional css_classes", width = 600)

div2 = Div(text = """
<p> This Bokeh Div adds the style classes:<p>
<pre>
.custom {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em; }
.custom-2 {
    border: 3px solid #14999A;
    background-color: whitesmoke; }
</pre> """)
div2.css_classes = ["custom", "custom-2"]

plot = figure()
plot.line(x = [1, 2], y = [3, 4])
tabs = [Panel(title = 'Tab1', child = plot)]
tabs.append(Panel(title = 'Tab2', child = div2))

save(column(p, Tabs(tabs = tabs, css_classes = ['tabs_class'], width = 600)), template = template)
view("css_classes_demo.html")
```

Result:
[image]